# Split vector at multiplicity of a number

Tags: r

I want to split a vector at a multiplicity of a number so giving vector **c(1:100)** I would like to receive vectors like:

```
c(1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91) 
c(2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92) 
..... 
c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

Note that i want the vector c(1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91)  to be the FIRST in the list of new vectors, because I know that split(1:100,1:100 %% 10)[1] is   c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100) which is not what I want

**EDIT**
The 1:100 example is just an example. In my app I want to split a vector of 256 numbers (random numbers not from 1 to 256) and divide it to 16 new vectors...

Comment: `split(1:100,1:100 %% 10)`, perhaps?

Comment: @joran, post as answer or find a duplicate? (I know, posting an answer is easier ...)

Comment: I tried it but then the first new vector is the one with 10,20,30 etc. So `split(1:100,1:100 %% 10)[1] = c(10,20............)`. I want the first out of 10 to be the one with 1,11,21..... and the last with 10,20.30....

Comment: There may be a way to do better, but `split(1:100,((1:100 %% 10) -1) %% 10)` would give the order you want

Comment: better: `split(1:100,0:99 %% 10)`

Comment: thanks @Chris the solution split(1:100,0:99 %% 10) is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `split(1:100,1:100 %% 10)`. Some options for ordering include:

```
x <- split(1:100,1:100 %% 10)
c(tail(x,-1),head(x,1))
```

or from the comments above,

```
split(1:100,((1:100 %% 10) -1) %% 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is uglier than joran's answer, but you could also do that in a loop, and use `grep()` to extract those numbers ending in a particular value:

```
yourlist <- vector("list", 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  yourlist[[i]] <- grep(paste0(i %% 10, "$"), 1:100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, perfect choice would be to make it like this:

```
split(1:100,0:99 %% 10)
```

In such case we can make it really generic so as:

```
split(vec, 0:(length(vec)-1) %% X)
```

where vec is the vector we want to divide and X is your multiplicity